# Sublime Text autocomplete suggestions looks corrupt, how to fix?

Tags: macos, autocomplete, sublimetext

[image: screenshot Sublime Text autocomplete]

Not sure what is happening to my installation of Sublime Text, when ever autocomplete drop down appears it is populated with a bunch of corrupted looking suggestions, this just started recently. I have Googled around and have not yet seen another person with the same issue. I've already tried uninstalling, throwing out User/me/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3 folder, and re-installing, but still the corrupted text shows up in my autocomplete. I am working on a Macbook Air, I also use a Macbook Pro at work with the same setup and have never seen this happen before?

Comment: that looks like base64. Do you have any strings like that in your file? Does this happen in every file you work on, or just particular ones?

Comment: Yes I do have a base64 image in there. That is odd that it is picking autocomplete suggestions from anywhere in that string rather than the whole string, since there are no spaces. I just gave it try on the same file different computer and yep it's happening there too. Thanks for helping me find the cause, now I just need to figure out how, or if, I can explicitly ignore this one string from autocomplete references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As established in the comments, you have [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded strings (likely an inline image) elsewhere in your file. Sublime's default autocomplete populates its choices menu with elements from your file, and uses fuzzy matching to bring up selections. Since base64 can contain all letters and numbers, chances are that any sequence you're typing may match, and that string will be brought to the top of the autocomplete dropdown.

There are a couple of ways around this. First, if the base64 content is actually scoped as a `string` (i.e., it's surrounded by single or double quotes), you can add the following line to your settings (**`Preferences -> Settings-User`**):

```js
"auto_complete_selector": "source - comment - string, meta.tag - punctuation.definition.tag.begin"
```

This should hopefully solve your problem for the time being, with the downside that you lose any other string-encoded information that you may wish to be in autocomplete.

You can also try using an autocomplete engine like [`SublimeCodeIntel`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeCodeIntel) (works for multiple languages, including JS) or [`TernJS`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/TernJS). These can have the option of turning off Sublime's internal autocomplete mechanism, and just filling in the choices with their generated content.